# Multiple Task in one controller

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, async-await, task

I have a MVC controller action that does n number of steps
like

```vb
Public ActionResult Index()
{
    GetDatFromTabelCustomer()
    GetDataFromWebApi()
    GetDataFromSession()
    GetyetAnotherData()
    SendItToView()
}
```

**I was going to wrap each method with `Task.Run`
 and then do `Task.WhenAll()` before i Process and `SendItToView()`.** But there are lot of blogs about why you should not use Task.Run
 and instead do async await, in this scenario i really do want to run parallel task instead of await on each one in serial fashion,
 there is some cost to stitch and tear-down thread from thread pool in doing so, but what other option do i have than doing Task.Run?

**Example**

```vb
Public ActionResult Index()
{
    Task taska = Task.Run(() => GetDatFromTabelCustomer())
    Task taskb = Task.Run(() => GetDataFromWebApi())
    Task taskc = Task.Run(() => GetDataFromSession())
    Task taskd = Task.Run(() => GetyetAnotherData())
    await taska;
    await taskb;
    await taskc;
    await taskd;

    string get resultA = taska.Result
    .
    .
    .
    SendItToView()
}
```

Comment: Your example does not make sense, in the first bit of code `GetDatFromTabelCustomer()` does not return anything but in the 2nd example it looks like it returns a `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to do it would be re-write your functions to be async than can be re-written to async, you can use Task.Run() for ones that don't expose a async API. You can also use `Task.WhenAll(` to combine all of the tasks in to one awaitable thing.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    Task<string> taska = GetDatFromTabelCustomerAsync());
    Task taskb = GetDataFromWebApiAsync());
    Task taskc = Task.Run( () =>     GetDataFromSession());
    Task taskd = Task.Run( () =>      GetyetAnotherData());

    await Task.WhenAll(taska, taskb, taskc, taskd);

    string resultA = await taska;

    SendItToView()
}
```

In  your example you showed `taska` returning a string, I fixed the code to do that. There is no cost to call `await` a 2nd time on a task and it is a better habit to have than to call `taska.Result`, you should never do a `.Result` from inside a async method.

[Here is a good article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) explaining how to convert from synchronous MVC code to async MVC code

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `Task.Run`. What you want is *concurrency* (multiple things at once), and not *parallelism* (multiple things on different threads at once). Parallelism is one form of concurrency, but you can also do *asynchronous concurrency* using `Task.WhenAll`.

To properly solve this, first start at your "leaves", that is, the actual database call, WebAPI call, etc. Make those endpoints asynchronous (e.g., using EF's async queries or `HttpClient`), and then let the `async` grow from there. Eventually, you will end up with a `GetDataFromTableCustomerAsync` and `GetDataFromWebApiAsync` methods that you can then consume in your controller method as such:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  var taska = GetDataFromTableCustomerAsync();
  var taskb = GetDataFromWebApiAsync();

  // Both the db query and WebAPI calls are in progress at this point.
  // So do anything *synchronous* that you want to do.
  // For example, reading session data is not I/O-bound; it should just be done synchronously.
  var sessionData = GetDataFromSession();

  // Now, (asynchronously) wait for all the asynchronous work to complete.
  await Task.WhenAll(taska, taskb);

  // And get the results.
  var resultA = await taska;
  var resultB = await taskb;

  SendItToView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those all appear to be IO intensive operations, so I suspect the use of Task.Run() really is not the way to go here. But, you can still use Task.WhenAll(). Each of your methods must return a Task, and will presumably use the async pattern to do their work. Then, do something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>()
tasks.Add(GetDataFromTableCustomer());
tasks.Add(GetDataFromWebApi());
...
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Also, since those methods return Task, it's a good idea to suffix their names with Async.